# Get Unique Tuples from List , Python

Tags: python, list, set

```
>>> a= ('one', 'a')
>>> b = ('two', 'b')
>>> c = ('three', 'a')
>>> l = [a, b, c]
>>> l
[('one', 'a'), ('two', 'b'), ('three', 'a')]
```

How can I check for only the elements of this list with a unique second entry (column? item?), and then grab the first entry found on the list.  Desired output is

```
>>> l
[('one', 'a'), ('two', 'b')]
```

Comment: Change ('three', 'c') to ('three', 'a') on the example on l output.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a set (if the second item is hash-able):

```
>>> lis = [('one', 'a'), ('two', 'b'), ('three', 'a')]
>>> seen = set()
>>> [item for item in lis if item[1] not in seen and not seen.add(item[1])]
[('one', 'a'), ('two', 'b')]
```

The above code is equivalent to:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> ans = []
for item in lis:
    if item[1] not in seen:
        ans.append(item)
        seen.add(item[1])
...         
>>> ans
[('one', 'a'), ('two', 'b')]
```

Comment: I finally understand this list comprehension.  The "seen.add()" code always returns None, so saying "and not... always None" is not a condition to check at all, just a way to sneak a command into the list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

If order isn't important, you can use a dictionary:

```
d = {}

for t in reversed(l):
    d[t[1]] = t

print d.values()
```

Or more concisely:

```
{t[1]: t for t in reversed(l)}.values()
```

If you don't reverse the list, `('three', 'a')` will overwrite `('one', 'a')`.